# how to combine strings with NAs in R

Tags: r, string

```
aa<-"apples and "
bb<-"banana"
cc<-"NA
dd<-"are good fruit"
ff<-paste(aa,bb,cc,dd, sep=" ")
ff

> ff
[1] "apples and  banana NA are good fruit"
```

*How to get "apples and  banana are good fruit"*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: do you have `NA` as string? Try `ff <- c(aa, bb, cc, dd);
paste0(ff[ff != "NA"], collapse = " ")` and if it is real `NA`, you can do `paste0(ff[!is.na(ff)], collapse = " ")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of `na.omit` and `c` functions to concatenate character vectors with `NA`. Please see the code below:

```
aa <- "apples and"
bb <- "bananas"
cc <- NA
dd <- "are good fruit"

ff<-paste(na.omit(c(aa, bb, cc, dd)), sep = " ", collapse = " ")
ff

# [1] "apples and  bananas are good fruit"
```